# Activate Bootstrap alerts with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and my problem is that I have a button in a modal such that when I click it, a JQuery script is run. I need this script to show an alert box.

The code:

```
<div id="formAlert" class="alert alert-warning hide">
    Please enter your    
</div>
```

The above is inside the modal.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function (){

            $("#submitMe").click(function(){
                $("#formAlert").show();
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Instead of this $("#formAlert").alert('show'); try this $("#formAlert").show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you'll need to hide the alert using `display: none` in CSS. You're achieving that using Bootstrap's `.hide` class, so that should be sufficient.

Next, [`alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert) isn't a proper function of a jQuery object. It's a function of the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object and is used to display a system alert.

You just need to use jQuery's [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function. You may also need to prevent the default action of the event (i.e. the submit button click) using [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). For example, your script should look like this:

```
$(function() {  
    $('#submitMe').on('click', function(e) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#formAlert').show();
    });
});
```

Notice that we use the [`$(function() {  })`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() {  });`.

Comment: Please put together a jsFiddle, or link to the demo.

Comment: Interestingly, this worked when I used the display: none in CSS. Thanks for your help by the way!